# I'm having trouble with this. I keep getting a run time error because it is printing 2 lines at the same time?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class AnimalDriver {

    public static void main ( String [] args ) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner ( System.in );
        String Type, Name, Type2, Name2;
        int Age, Weight, Age2, Weight2;

        System.out.println ("Enter Animal #1's type: ");
        Type = input.nextLine();


        System.out.println ("Enter Animal #1's name: ");
        Name = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println ("Enter Animal #1's weight in pounds: ");
        Weight = input.nextInt();


        System.out.println ( "Enter Animal #1's age in years: ");
        Age = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println ("Enter Animal #2's type: ");
        Type2 = input.nextLine();


        System.out.println ("Enter Animal #2's name: ");
        Name2 = input.nextLine();


        System.out.println ("Enter Animal #2's weight in pounds: ");
        Weight2 = input.nextInt();


        System.out.println ( "Enter Animal #2's age in years: ");
        Age2 = input.nextInt();


        Animal Trial1 = new Animal (Type, Name, Age, Weight);
        Animal Trial2 = new Animal (Type2,Name2,Age2,Weight2);

        System.out.println(Trial1);
        System.out.println(Trial2);

    }
}
```

So that's my code so far and I have a custom class included but there's no need for that ATM. So the problem I'm having is that after running it, everything is going fine but after inputing the Animal #1's year, it simeultaneously prints Animal #2's type and name at the same time. this makes it impossible for me to input a value for type and just leaves it as a white space. Does anyone know the fix for this? Any help is greatly aprreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Between `Age = input.nextInt();` and `Type2 = input.nextLine();` and another `input.nextLine()`

The problem is, there is still a carriage return/new line in the `input` buffer and the call to `nextInt`, which `nextLine` is picking up and is therefore skipping over your `Type2 = input.nextLine();` (leaving it blank)

Any time you DON'T use `nextLine` to get input (and you want a new line of input), you will need to call `nextLine` first...

Comment: Wow that's very simple, but can you explain to me why there was an error and how did adding that line just fix it? I like to understand things conceptually not just get answers although yours is appreciated. EDIT: NVM Im not sure if you edited your answer to explain it after I wrote this or I didnt expand it in the first place, MY BAD, ignore this comment.

Comment: Why should there be?  You could have a line of text with lots of mixed content and you might want to read through a bunch of ints, doubles and other mixed data.  This is simply how `Scanner` workers

Comment: Sorry, I'm kinda new to java, can you explain in simpler terms your 2nd statemment about why it occurs? I do not quite understanding what you are saying in your comment?

Comment: When you press the [enter] key, the `Scanner` will have whatever you typed PLUS a new line character in it's stream, for example `123\n`, when you use `nextInt`, the `Scanner` reads in the `123` from the stream, but the `\n` is still there.  The next time you call `nextLine`, `Scanner` goes, "Oh look and new line character" and returns you back an empty `String` (because there is nothing in the stream before the `\n`).

Comment: Scanner isn't just used for processing user input, but imagine they entered `123 banana 456.789`, you could use `nextInt` (`123`), `next`, `next` (`banana`), `next`, `nextDouble` (`456.789`) to process the text (or something simular, I don't use `Scanner` personally)

Comment: Wow thanks a lot, this really cleared up my understanding of it. Thank you for taking the time to help me with this. I really appreciate it.